# IXSLTemplate (MSXML 6) - how to resolve xsl:import

Tags: delphi, xslt, msxml6

I am using mxsml 6 via COM to execute a transform. The source stylesheet has an xs:import statement that I know how to include, but how can I tell MSXML to do that? I can't seem to find a place to tell the IXSLTemplate to load the resolved source

Details:

- I get the error "the system cannot locate the object specified"
- I am setting the ResolveExternals = true on the source document
- I am trying to execute a schematron validation
- I am using Delphi, so using msxml seems to be my only option
- I have everything in memory in a server environment, so I very much want to avoid having to use files

Code:

```
var
  v: variant;
  doc : IXMLDOMDocument2;
  xform: IXSLTemplate;
begin
  v := CreateOLEObject('MSXML2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument.6.0')
  doc := IUnknown(TVarData(v).VDispatch) as IXMLDomDocument2;
  doc.async := false;
  doc.resolveExternals := true;
  doc.loadXML([my source for the first transform below]);
  v := CreateOLEObject('MSXML2.XSLTemplate.6.0');
  xform := IUnknown(TVarData(v).VDispatch) as IXSLTemplate;
  xform.stylesheet := doc;
end;
```

original source for transforms:

- http://gforge.hl7.org/gf/project/fhir/scmsvn/?action=browse&path=%2Ftrunk%2Fbuild%2Ftools%2Fschematron%2Fiso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl&view=markup
- http://gforge.hl7.org/gf/project/fhir/scmsvn/?action=browse&path=%2Ftrunk%2Fbuild%2Ftools%2Fschematron%2Fiso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl&revision=1319&view=markup

Comment: well, even if that problem can be solved - which looks unlikely - it's still not xslt 2. The Altova XML control is way easier to use (though has this same problem - have to use files)

Comment: You might be interested in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991755/how-do-i-resolve-xslimport-and-xslinclude-elements-with-relative-paths-whe?rq=1 (Although it is a .Net question.)

Comment: no. only .net has a solution for this

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a delphi programmer, but I've done this often with C++ for MSXML4.   Here is the vb code example from MSXML4 documentation, that I simply translated to C++.

```
 Dim xslt As New Msxml2.XSLTemplate40
 Dim xslDoc As New Msxml2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument40
 Dim xmlDoc As New Msxml2.DOMDocument40
 Dim xslProc As IXSLProcessor
 xslDoc.async = False
 xslDoc.Load "sample.xsl"
 Set xslt.stylesheet = xslDoc
 xmlDoc.async = False
 xmlDoc.Load "books.xml"
 Set xslProc = xslt.createProcessor()
 xslProc.input = xmlDoc
 xslProc.addParameter "param1", "Hello"
 xslProc.Transform
 MsgBox xslProc.output
```